# Justify hebrew text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, hebrew, text-manipulation

I want to justify hebrew text but cannot do so , i have added centering for a heading.
even when i remove centering the text is not justified

```
\documentclass[hebrew]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,nohead,twoside,top=2.5cm,bindingoffset=1.5cm,hmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\selectlanguage{hebrew}
   \centering


מחקר זה בוצע בפיקוחו של פרופסור דפנה ויס, הפקולטה להנדסה ביו רפואית, פרופסור נח לוטן, הפקולטה להנדסה ביו רפואית ופרופסור יורם ברעם, הפקולטה למדעי מחשב , בטכניון, המכון טכנולוגי לישראל.
       \\[0.3in]

        \textbf{\Large \textsc{ תודות}} 
       \\[0.1in]

אני מודה לפרופסורים להדרכה, הסבלנות והאמונה בי שלהם.
 אני מודה להוריו ואחות  שנתנן לי  תמיכה  רגשית 
. ואחרון אך לא פחות חשוב את החברים וקרובי המשפחה שהיו שם  תמיד בשבילי.
\\\hfill


הכרת תודה מסורה לטכניון על מימון מחקר זה.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2):

I see no problems with justifying text in Hebrew.

Just remember that the `flushleft` and `flushright` environments have the opposite meaning than in latin languages.

For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,nohead,twoside,top=2.5cm,bindingoffset=1.5cm,hmargin=2.5cm,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel} % english is only for the example

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}
\noindent Justified text

\bigskip\medskip

\selectlanguage{hebrew}
\noindent מחקר זה בוצע בפיקוחו של פרופסור דפנה ויס, הפקולטה להנדסה ביו רפואית, פרופסור נח לוטן, הפקולטה להנדסה ביו רפואית ופרופסור יורם ברעם, הפקולטה למדעי מחשב , בטכניון, המכון טכנולוגי לישראל.
מחקר זה בוצע בפיקוחו של פרופסור דפנה ויס, הפקולטה להנדסה ביו רפואית, פרופסור נח לוטן, הפקולטה להנדסה ביו רפואית ופרופסור יורם ברעם, הפקולטה למדעי מחשב , בטכניון, המכון טכנולוגי לישראל.

\bigskip\bigskip

\selectlanguage{english}
\begin{flushleft}
Left aligned text (you have to use \texttt{flushright} instead of \texttt{flushleft} for Hebrew)
\end{flushleft}

\selectlanguage{hebrew}
\begin{flushright}
מחקר זה בוצע בפיקוחו של פרופסור דפנה ויס, הפקולטה להנדסה ביו רפואית, פרופסור נח לוטן, הפקולטה להנדסה ביו רפואית ופרופסור יורם ברעם, הפקולטה למדעי מחשב , בטכניון, המכון טכנולוגי לישראל.
מחקר זה בוצע בפיקוחו של פרופסור דפנה ויס, הפקולטה להנדסה ביו רפואית, פרופסור נח לוטן, הפקולטה להנדסה ביו רפואית ופרופסור יורם ברעם, הפקולטה למדעי מחשב , בטכניון, המכון טכנולוגי לישראל.
\end{flushright}

\bigskip

\selectlanguage{english}
\begin{flushright}
Right aligned text (you have to use \texttt{flushleft} instead of \texttt{flushright} for Hebrew)
\end{flushright}

\selectlanguage{hebrew}
\begin{flushleft}
מחקר זה בוצע בפיקוחו של פרופסור דפנה ויס, הפקולטה להנדסה ביו רפואית, פרופסור נח לוטן, הפקולטה להנדסה ביו רפואית ופרופסור יורם ברעם, הפקולטה למדעי מחשב , בטכניון, המכון טכנולוגי לישראל.
מחקר זה בוצע בפיקוחו של פרופסור דפנה ויס, הפקולטה להנדסה ביו רפואית, פרופסור נח לוטן, הפקולטה להנדסה ביו רפואית ופרופסור יורם ברעם, הפקולטה למדעי מחשב , בטכניון, המכון טכנולוגי לישראל.
\end{flushleft}

\bigskip

\selectlanguage{english}
\begin{center}
Centered text
\end{center}

\selectlanguage{hebrew}
\begin{center}
מחקר זה בוצע בפיקוחו של פרופסור דפנה ויס, הפקולטה להנדסה ביו רפואית, פרופסור נח לוטן, הפקולטה להנדסה ביו רפואית ופרופסור יורם ברעם, הפקולטה למדעי מחשב , בטכניון, המכון טכנולוגי לישראל.
מחקר זה בוצע בפיקוחו של פרופסור דפנה ויס, הפקולטה להנדסה ביו רפואית, פרופסור נח לוטן, הפקולטה להנדסה ביו רפואית ופרופסור יורם ברעם, הפקולטה למדעי מחשב , בטכניון, המכון טכנולוגי לישראל.
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Your example should contain at least three lines of text per paragraph, so we see the justification of the first two.